# Drastic change in footer

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I wrote a footer using aura components ,the footer looks good in chrome but when it comes to ie11 it is behaving differently.

The complete footer faded out.Let me know if any one can help on this issue

Attached is the screen shot of my footer[ie 11  [image: ][1]]

Comment: if poosible i can send the code via email

Comment: Add your code to question here .Also describe whether component is for community cloud or sales or service edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a waste of your efforts. Per the [Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/getstart_browsers_sfx.htm?edition=&impact=), support for IE11 ends with SU16 release. I wouldn't recommend putting effort into solving an issue that won't have any Salesforce support a short time from now.

- Existing orgs will be able to continue to use IE11 until Dec 17th, 2016.
- Users of new orgs created after Summer ’16 can’t use IE11 to access Lightning Experience. Instead, IE11 users are automatically redirected to Salesforce Classic.
- It isn't clearly stated in the release notes, but I believe the redirection to Salesforce Classic is what will happen to users in existing orgs after Dec 17th 2016.

For more details about this change, see [Retirement of Support for Accessing Lightning Experience and Salesforce1 Using Internet Explorer 11](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Retirement-of-Support-for-Microsoft-Internet-Explorer-version-11-with-Lightning-Experience&language=en_US).